# SQL Server adding characters to the end of a string

Tags: sql-server, string, function, concatenation

I have created a SQL Server function which takes in a piped sequence of numbers, transforms the numbers into their corresponding names using a lookup table, and then joins the names together separated by commas, and returns a single string.

The function is working fine except it is not joining the string together. My code is below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_GetNotifyUsersFromIDString
   (@IDString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @UsersDisplay VARCHAR(MAX)

   DECLARE @UserID VARCHAR(255)
   DECLARE @UserDisplay VARCHAR(255)
   DECLARE @DelimPos INT

   DECLARE @WorkingString VARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @WorkingString = @IDString

   WHILE (@WorkingString <> '') 
   BEGIN
        SET @DelimPos = CHARINDEX( '|', @WorkingString)

        IF @DelimPos > 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @UserID = LEFT(@WorkingString, @DelimPos-1)
            SET @WorkingString = RIGHT(@WorkingString, LEN(@WorkingString) - @DelimPos)
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @UserID = @WorkingString
            SET @WorkingString = ''
        END

        SET @UsersDisplay = @UsersDisplay + ',' + (SELECT lookup FROM VW_LOOKUP_SecurityUser WHERE ID = @UserID)
    END

    RETURN @UsersDisplay
END
```

and to run it I use:

```
PRINT dbo.UDF_GetNotifyUsersFromIDString('1|2|3|2|3|')
```

If I do the following:

```
SET @UsersDisplay = (SELECT lookup FROM VW_LOOKUP_SecurityUser)
```

and check each iteration, the correct values are being assigned, but when I ask it to join them, it is returning a blank entry. I suspect my method of joining the string incorrect,  but cannot find an alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is You have not initialized your `@UsersDisplay` variable which will be `NULL` default. **NULL + any value is NULL** so you are not getting any result.

So you can do two things here one is

**initializing the variable**

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2008+` then

```
DECLARE @UsersDisplay VARCHAR(MAX)=''
```

else

```
DECLARE @UsersDisplay VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @UsersDisplay=''

SET @UsersDisplay = @UsersDisplay + ','
                    + (SELECT Coalesce(lookup,'')
                       FROM   VW_LOOKUP_SecurityUser
                       WHERE  ID = @UserID)
```

**Another way is by using `ISNULL` or `Coalesce` function**

```
SET @UsersDisplay = Coalesce(@UsersDisplay,'') + ',' + 
                    (SELECT Coalesce(lookup,'')
                     FROM   VW_LOOKUP_SecurityUser 
                     WHERE  ID = @UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the result of the last statement. If one lookup return `NULL` the result is `NULL`. Also you have to initialize the variable `@UsersDisplay`. `DECLARE @UsersDisplay VARCHAR(MAX) = '';`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a null value somewhere in that string, and it's nulling out the entire result. Try something like this in your concatenation:

```
SET @UsersDisplay = @UsersDisplay + ',' + (SELECT COALESCE(lookup,'') FROM VW_LOOKUP_SecurityUser WHERE ID = @UserID)
```